# How to interact with boolean variables inside of if statements and outside of them. C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to assign a bool variable if it is true or false according to a if statement. But after that I want to use the same variable outside of the if statement for a different if statement and use it as a condition. Is there any way to interact with the bool created inside of an if statement also outside of the if statement? It is written in C#.

This is an example:

```
 string enteredPassword = Console.ReadLine();

 if (enteredPassword == "magic")
 {
     bool passwordIsValid = true;
 }
 else
 {
     bool passwordIsValid = false;
 }

 if (passwordIsValid)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Access Granted!");
 }
 else
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Access Denied!");
 }
```

I want to use variable `passwordIsValid` to determine if the if function should be triggered or moved on to else. Thanks

Comment: Simple move the declaration above the if block.

Comment: You don't need an `if` statement at all. The value you want to assign is the result of evaluating the condition: `bool passwordIsValid = enteredPassword == "magic";`

Comment: Some basic reading about [_variable scope_](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/)